# System of integer inequalities: Counting solutions

Tags: matrix

I have a system of inequalities and constraints:

```
Let A=[F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6] where F1 through F6 are given.
Let B=[a,b,c,d,e,f] where a<=b<=c<=d<=e<=f.
Let C=[u,v,w,x,y,z] where u<=v<=w<=x<=y<=z.

Equation 1: if(a>F1, 1, 0) + if(a>F2, 1, 0) + ... + if(f>F6, 1, 0) > 18
Equation 2: if(u>a, 1, 0) + if(u>b, 1, 0) + ... + if (z>f, 1, 0) > 18
Equation 3: if(F1>u, 1, 0) + if(F1>v, 1, 0) + ... + if(F6>z, 1, 0) > 18

Other constraints: All variables must be integers between 1 and N (N is given).
```

I wish to merely count the number of integer solutions to my variables (I do not wish to actually solve them). I know how to use solvers to calculate systems of equations in matrices but this usually assumes those equations use = as opposed to >=, >, <, or <=.

Comment: See my answer below,But I think I totally missed the point.   Are we looking for all the points (A,B,C) that satisfy all 3 equations, where 0<A<N, 0<B<N, 0<C<N?

Comment: is this what we're trying to do?  http://www.purplemath.com/modules/syslneq.htm

Comment: Looking for all combinations of points a,b,c,d,e,f,u,v,w,x,y,z that satisfy the three equations and the constraints.

Comment: Re: that link, I think it's likely something like this, yes. But I have no idea what the shape of the lines look like; I have many variables here and they are technically if-statements.

Comment: all combination of points (a,b), (c,d), (e,f), (u,v)...
or (a,u), (b,v), (c,w)... ?

Comment: All combinations of points as listed (a,b,c,d,e,f,u,v,w,x,y,z)

Comment: The A B C thing is technically not relevant to the equations

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab at it.

This is horribly inefficient, as I compute the Cartesian product of the two vectors, then compare each tuple combination.  This also won't scale past 2 dimensions.

Also, I'm worried this isn't exactly what you are looking for, because I'm solving each equation independently. If you're looking for all the integer values that satisfy a 3-dimensional space bound by the system of inequalities, well, that's a bit of a brain bender for me, albeit very interesting.

Python anyone?

```
#sample data
A =[12,2,15,104,54,20]
B =[10,20,30,40,50,60]
C =[100,200,300,400,500,600]

import itertools
def eq1():
    product = itertools.product(B,A)  #construct Cartesian product of 2 lists

    #list(product) returns a Cartesian product of tuples
    # [(12, 10), (12, 20), (12, 30)... (2, 10), (2, 20)... (20, 60)]

    #now, use a list comprehension to compare the values in each tuple,
    # generating a list of only those that satisfy the inequality...
    #  then return the length of that list - which is the count
    return len([ Bval for Bval, Aval in list(product) if Bval > Aval])


def eq2():
    product = itertools.product(C,B)
    return len([ Cval for Cval, Bval in list(product) if Cval>Bval])

def eq3():
    product = itertools.product(A,C)
    return len([ Aval for Aval, Cval in list(product) if Aval>Cval])


print eq1()
print eq2()
print eq3()
```

This sample data returns:
eq1 : 21
eq2 : 36
eq3 : 1

But doesn't know how to combine these answers into a single integer count of all 3 - there's some kind of union that's going to happen between the lists.

My sanity test is in equation 3, which returns '1' - because only when Aval = 104 does it satisfy Aval > Cval for Cval only at 100.